# Disable Autosaved Labels in Jira

Tags: jira

I would like to understand if Autosave labels can be disabled in Jira. My client does not want autosaved labels to appear as suggestions in Labels field when raising a Jira support ticket (Ex: as a precaution that people won't select a wrong label that could be misleading) My question:-

1. Is there possibility in Jira to disable autosave function for particular labels in Jira without removing / deleting the labels ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "autosaved labels"? Do you just mean that (at least in most configurations that I've seen), anyone can create arbitrary labels by editing an issue?

Comment: As the Jira fan I am, I believe this question is a bit too specific to the software itself rather than the practice of project management. Besides, these options are usually set at admin level, so end users can't do much to tweak such settings.

Comment: Sounds like it is the popup that displays possible labels that is the problem, rather than the autosave.
Have you pointed out to the client that they will otherwise end up with multiple spellings of the same label and multiple labels that all really mean the same thing?